# How to write data to a .csv file, from accessing a url (perhaps using .php to capture data at the end of the url)

Tags: php, csv, curl, input, get

I'm new to programming.
I've been researching my problem for a while.
I'm doing a project with arduino. I already know how to make connections and everything, I have no doubts about the Arduino or its modules.

At this point, my question is, how to create a script (maybe a .php) to do the following function:

"Write the data at the end of a URL to a .csv file"

The idea is: I access a url like http://my site . com/XYZ_38.5

So this script adds the number 38.5 to my .csv file.

The file would look like this:

```
37.5
38.0
38.0
36.0
36.5
38.5 (that was the insertion)
39.0 (this will be the next insert, when I access the url http://my site . com/XYZ_39.0)
```

Can anyone help me how to do this? I have an instance on AWS, I intend to implement there. I intend to do this collection method for temperature data to one decimal place. Something similar to ThingSpeak, but only for my use and using .csv.

Answer (score 0):

This very easy to use thingspeak api if your csv just contains numbers. (thingspeak.com).

Tutorial:
[https://community.thingspeak.com/tutorials/arduino/send-data-to-thingspeak-with-arduino](https://community.thingspeak.com/tutorials/arduino/send-data-to-thingspeak-with-arduino/)/

You can also add the thingspeak library to arduino. There are examples included in the library.

Basically this is what happens in thingspeak -

1. You have to create a new channel in thingspeak.
2. They will give you a url to call.  When you call that url with field values, it will be saved.
   You can also view the data in charts and download the csv file.

The other option in use ifttt webhoocks. It will let you add rows to google sheet using it.

So you don't need to have a php server or anything.  But you need an internet connection for arduino. You can use an ethernet shield or a wifi module. But if you haven't bought an arduino yet, I would recommend you to buy a NodeMcu which has built in wifi and you can use thingspeak library examples on it without hard modifications.